# VBScript: Connection to ODBC Fails with error message "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Tags: database, vbscript, odbc, database-connection

I have the below code, which is throwing me an error "Operation is not allowed when object is closed". What am I missing here?

```
 Dim dbconnect, dbresults

 Set dbconnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set dbresult = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

dbconnectString =  "driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;System=***;UID=***;PWD=***;Naming=1"
dbconnect.Open (dbconnectString)        
mySQLQuerry ="Select XOORIG  from FIQDLIB.FSFPXO as400xo WHERE as400xo.xoefdt = 1130418 and as400xo.xotrsq in (75440)"
dbresult.Open mySQLQuerry, dbconnect
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [connection state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675068) with `WScript.Echo dbconnect.State` after you opened the connection. Also your connection string looks off. According to [this page](http://connectionstrings.com/as-400#ibm-iseries-access-odbc-driver) the driver name should be in curly brackets.